# LaunchScreen in dark/light mode depending on appearance?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I am setting appearance programmatically, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
guard let theme: Bool = keyValueStore.getValue(for: .themeSwitch) else {
        keyValueStore.set(value: false, for: .themeSwitch)
        return
    }

rootWindow?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = theme ? .dark : .light
```

everything working fine on app start, except LaunchScreen, it doesn't know anything about my theme. It knows only plist `UIUserInterfaceStyle` value, which is by default is light in my app, but in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I change it with code above.

Comment: The launch screen is shown before your app is run. There's no way to change it based on some runtime calculation.

Comment: On a separate note, is there really a reason to offer a separate setting in your app for dark/light mode? Why not simply honor the current system setting (in other words, don't use any override)?

Comment: good question, but it's not my decision)

Comment: can you use a storyboard at launch instead?

Comment: @HangarRash - my interpretation is that it was an attempt to make the feature work  well, from day 1. They could have left it out, but they probably realized that devs would be in scenarios where they would want to pick (or force) one over another, and it would allow you to build "one of each appearance" for testers, etc.

Comment: @benc *"my interpretation"* - your interpretation of what? *"is that it was..."* - what is "it"? *"the feature"* - what feature? *"They could have..."* - who's they? Apple? *"pick (or force) one over..."* - what is "one" here? *"and it would allow..."* - what is "it"?

Comment: @HangarRash Your comment about the "is there really a reason to offer a separate setting in your app for dark/light mode?"... we prob should make this a separate question... :)

Answer (score -2):

The HIG's long-standing opinion is the launch displays (there have been three different ways to implement) should **NOT** function as "splash screens."

The latest approach `UILaunchScreen` was added in iOS 14+, which is after Dark Mode... but the most important change that you can have apps with no storyboards...

The HIG tries to address this topic, by talking about it

> Design a launch screen that’s nearly identical to the first screen of your app. If you include elements that look different when the app finishes launching, people may experience an unpleasant flash between the launch screen and the first screen of the app. Also make sure that your launch screen matches the device’s current appearance, such as Dark Mode

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/launching

Descriptively, this page tries to suggest that you can make a launch screen that would work with multiple orientations as well, but I lack the imagination to think of solution.

At this point, you should use a storyboard for launching, because AFAIK, it can support all the scenarios well.

You didn't say anything about the history of your project, like if its old enough to have the older launch-storyboards... but one thing to be aware of is that pre-Dark mode storyboards are not auto-magically converted... they have a tendency to be pro-Light mode...

But if you create a new storyboard, the template uses the newer semantic colors that adapt to Appearance. You can update your legacy storyboard to do this as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question at all. The OP is already using a launch screen. The question is asking how to have the launch screen honor the app's current (overridden) light/dark mode. A launch screen can only honor the device's current light/dark mode, not the app's chosen mode.

Comment: So, the answer is "no"? The launch screen is mode-less, it doesn't have any way to honor the mode, AFAIK. The only thing is to design something that is inoffensively visually "between" the look of light and dark UI when launched.

Comment: The launch screen is not mode-less. It honors the device's current mode. But that is not what the OP wants. But otherwise your last comment is basically what your answer should be since your current answer doesn't address the question at all.